# Remove a semicolon in a string by JavaScript

Tags: javascript

How can I remove the semicolon (`;`) from a string by using JavaScript?

For example:

```
var str = '<div id="confirmMsg" style="margin-top: -5px;">'
```

How can I remove the semicolon from `str`?

Comment: I rolled this back to contain the actual, original example; check the source in the history to see that this was the original example, Gumbo had just fixed the formatting.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You can use the `replace` method of the string object. Here is what [W3Schools](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/W3Schools) says about it: *[JavaScript replace()](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_replace.asp)*.

In your case you could do something like the following:

```
str = str.replace(";", "");
```

You can also use a regular expression:

```
str = str.replace(/;/g, "");
```

This will replace all semicolons globally. If you wish to replace just the first instance you would remove the `g` from the first parameter.

Answer (score 9):

Try this:

```
str = str.replace(/;/g, "");
```

This will remove all semicolons in `str` and assign the result back to `str`.

Answer (score 6):

Depending upon exactly why you need to do this, you need to be cautious of edge cases:

For instance, what if your string is this (contains two semicolons):

```
'<div id="confirmMsg" style="margin-top: -5px; margin-bottom: 5px;">'
```

Any solution like

```
 str.replace(";", "");
```

will give you:

```
'<div id="confirmMsg" style="margin-top: -5px margin-bottom: 5px">'
```

which is invalid.

In this situation you're better off doing this:

```
 str.replace(";\"", "\"");
```

which will only replace ;" at the end of the style string.

In addition I wouldn't worry about removing it anyway. It shouldn't matter - unless you have already determined that for your situation it does matter for some obscure reason. It's more likely to lead to hard-to-debug problems later if you try to get too clever in a situation like this.

Comment: +1 for mentioning that there is no obvious reson to remove the semicolon (and for the edge cases).

Comment: just need to mention that the case given in question was not given by the asker but by Gumbo in an edit. Check out the edit history.

Comment: No, it wasn't added by Gumbo in his edit. The example was there, but as it was raw, unquoted HTML, it was stripped out when Stack Overflow rendered it; view the source on the original post to confirm. Gumbo just fixed the formatting so the example would display.

Answer (score 2):

```
str = str.replace(";", "");
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
str = str.replace(/;/ig,'');
```

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion. Please also try not to crowd your code with explanatory comments, as this reduces the readability of both the code and the explanations!